# Build error with Windows 8 and Code::Blocks + MinGW

Tags: windows-8, mingw, code-blocks

A few days ago, I upgraded to Windows 8, and since that day, I have had a problem with Code::Blocks + MinGW. I've checked my path and ensured that it is set properly. Here is a screenshot of every run:

[image: "process terminated with status 1" error message]

The red Build Log error message reads:

> process terminated with status 1

This is affecting all my programs and I don't have any idea how to fix it. When I used Windows 7, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Since the error says "check for the existence of the EXE", does the EXE by that name actually exist in that path?

Comment: Can you try checking the [execution working directory](http://brogue.createforumhosting.com/compile-with-code-blocks-terminated-with-status-1-t425.html)?

Comment: I'll bet the path environment variable got reset or something, reinstall Code::Blocks and it'll probably fix itself.

Answer (score 1):

"How to Solve CodeBlocks environment error."

1. Go to "Settings"----"Compiler"----"Selected compiler"( GNU GCC Compiler ).
2. Than, Selected "Toolchain executables".
3. Now,  "( C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW )"

See video: https://youtu.be/Tb1VnXs60Lg